# How to translate Application Authorization Window Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

Where can I go to translate this text? Or force the text in french?

[image: I want to translate what's in red box]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, permission titles and descriptions are not yet localized (or localizable) in different languages.